# How to wait in script until device is connected

Tags: bash, contiki

I have a Sky wireless sensor node and a script which prints the output from the node.

```
sudo ./serialdump-linux -b115200 /dev/tmotesky1
```

If I start this script before my pc detects the node, I get the following error:

```
/dev/tmotesky1: No such file or directory
```

But if I wait for example 20 seconds, I miss the initial prints (which are important).

Is there a way to detect if the /dev/tmotesky1 exists?
Something like

```
while [ ! -f /dev/tmotesky1 ] ; do sleep 1; print 'Waiting...'; done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your idea should work. You might also want to look at the [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) project as  a way of blocking until the file is created.

Comment: Not too sure on my scripting, but you MAY need "-c" rather than "-f" for a character device special file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates that you are using Linux where you can use the hotplugging mechanism.

On generic systems, you can write an udev rule (--> see with `udevadmin monitor -e` what happens when you attach the device) which starts e.g. a program or writes something into a pipe.  When systemd is used, you can start a service (see `man systemd.device`).

On small/embedded systems it is possible to write a custom `/sbin/hotplug` program (set in `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug`) instead of using `udev`.